# How to compare date format in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I would like to extract data where all the records were created after 19:00:00 yesterday until now. What I have so far is :

```
Select * from table where lstupdt >=trunc(sysdate -1);
```

How to specify after 19:00:00 hours?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm . . . How about this?

```
where lstupdt >= trunc(sysdate - 1) + 19 / 24
```

Or, alternatively, to be more accurate:

```
where lstupdt >= trunc(sysdate - 1, 'day') + interval '19' hour
```

or:

```
where lstupdt >= trunc(sysdate, 'day') - interval '5' hour
```

Comment: Thanks. . Let me try n let you know